# Testflight: Push to Apple Watch

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch, testflight, ios9

We are using Testflight to let some of our users test the upcoming versions. One of these users has an iPhone 6 and a Apple Watch. His iPhone 6 has iOS9 GM installed. He does receive push notifications on his iPhone. But these notifications won't show up on his watch. We do not have a watch for testing, so my question is:

In Testflight-apps, are push-notifications able to be handed over to the watch? Are there any restrictions?

Comment: In TestFlight apps?  What are they?

Comment: i meant to say: "an app distributed via testflight"

Comment: They are no different to normal apps.

Comment: thats what i think, too. then we need to take a deeper look into this issue.

Comment: You need to start logging whats going on to a file in the app's document folder and enable file sharing so the test user can email it to you.